# libuvc not setting image size correctly

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, logitech

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying use an HD web cam for tracking QR codes, but when I tell libuvc to output a 720X1280 image I get a 640X480 one. here is the launch file code for libuvc

```
<node pkg="libuvc_camera" type="camera_node" name="logitech_cam">
        <param name="vendor" type="string" value="0x046d"/>
        <param name="product" type="string" value="0x082d" />
        <param name="serial" type="string" value="D016F4DF" />
        <param name="image_width" type="int" value="1280"/>
        <param name="image_height" type="int" value="720"/>
        <param name="pixle_format" type="string" value="mjpeg"/>
        <param name="auto_focus" type="bool" value="True" />
</node>
```

does anyone why it is sending the wrong sized image?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133101/libuvc-not-setting-image-size-correctly/) by [AlphaOne](https://answers.ros.org/users/4021/alphaone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The parameters you want are `width` and `height` (no `image_` prefix). I think you'll also need to set `video_mode=uncompressed`, as mjpeg isn't implemented yet (and there's no `pixel_format` parameter).

Auto focus isn't configurable (needs to be implemented in libuvc_camera and in libuvc), but it should be turned on by default in most cameras.

---

Originally posted by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) with karma: 438 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0